# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [103] Requested image not exists in product images' gallery

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I need to remove image using Soap **ApiSOAP V2 (WS-I Compliance Mode)**
I double checked image.image is exists.but alwas soap given above extension.
here is my code

```
$removeimg=new stdClass();
$file=$removeimg->file=$mediafiledel;
$id=$removeimg->productId=$mediaproductid;

try{
$result = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaRemove($sessionId,$id,$file);
}
catch (SoapFault $e) {
  echo 'sorry... our service is down';
}
```

Comment: what is value in $file ? it require file name with full path example "/b/l/blackberry8100_2.jpg"

Comment: It is not_exists fault from soap that means requested file not exist OR is not assigned to that product

Comment: value of file  as same as /b/l/blackberry8100_2.jpg

Comment: if file really exist and you are getting error means that image is not assigned to product.double check this

Comment: yes. that's the problam.

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is `not_exists` fault from soap that means requested file not exist
>   OR is not assigned to that product